# How do I restrict access to a folder and its contents based on a session variable value

Tags: php

I am building a web catalog website and I have all of my admin related pages in one folder called 'Admin'. How can I restrict access to that folder and its files (.php .html..) so that only admins can access it?

Comment: You've mentioned a session variable, do you already have cookie-based authentication on your app?

Comment: @alganet I don't have cookie based authentication. only a simple session variable gets set to "loggedin" upon successful log in. i could do the same for the admin pages but i would prefer to just to it to the folder and not repeat the code in everypage

Comment: Do you have some automatically prepended file?  You can easily do a check there.

Comment: @user521180 do your pages inside the admin folder have a common included file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have found a solution. its not exactly what i asked (it doesnt use session variables) but it does the job

http://davidwalsh.name/password-protect-directory-using-htaccess